# Gitlab duplicate pipelines for merged results and merge train

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-delivery, merge-request

When I enable both merged results pipeline and merge trains, two pipelines will be triggered, one for merged results and the other for merge train.

My question is that, why do we even bother waste time to run the one for merge results? Because the result of the merge train pipeline itself already perfectly validates the changes of the merge request, doesn't it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I see the same behavior. When I submit my MR, a detached merge result pipeline is triggered.

And after I click on "Start merge train" a new pipeline is run, even when I'm the one starting the merge train.

Comment: @X3ro please let me know the answer if you have it

Comment: @divine no answer yet, still waiting.